# StoredProcedure with Mono c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, mono

Can I use MySql Stored Procedure for my Mono C# Gtk+ app for Ubuntu?

I have try with..

> using [MySql.Data.MySqlClient](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=74598739018559969475);

```
// Prepare connecting to the database.
myConn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=table;uid=root;password=1234;");
cmd = myConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = @"Call newRow()";

myConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConn.Close();
```

If I just make and hardcode sql string in my program, it work!

Like..

> cmd.CommandText = @"insert into table ...

The problem is with the:

> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

-Line.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error with the Open call, your connection string is wrong. That has nothing to do with your command.

That said, I think your command should only contain the stored procedures name. Just "newRow" without any additional database syntax like call or empty brackets.

Comment: usp just an old comment.. no error on Open call.. hmm.. the 'Call newRow()' work it I run it from my sqlwork-bench.. The CommandType.StoredProcedure line gets red so..

Answer (score 0):

Ok so.. Just remove the..

> ```
> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
> ```

The MySql.Data.MySqlClient do not need this option to do Stored Procedure :)